# simplexml_load_string() just storing string of xml issue

Tags: php, xml, curl

I've been frustrated all day with this issue, I have to say. A website I'm working on utilises a REST based API to receive company data. Using cURL, I have the XML request and response coming back to me okay.

However, once I try to use `simplexml_load_string()` to change that XML into an array, it just stores the XML as a string inside one index of the array. Below, you can see my code along with a print screen of how the array looks in Google Chrome's developer tools.

**Code:**

```
$ch = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "requestXmlStr={$xml_data}");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    $output = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    $searchResults = simplexml_load_string($output);
    exit(print_r($searchResults));
```

The `exit(print_r($searchResults))` just displays the following on the page:

> SimpleXMLElement Object ( [0] =>
>   24/06/2014 15:47:38 companysearch UK 6.0 www.creditsafe.com
>   1 1 1 25 PSR DESIGN LIMITED 08821170 UK
>   HAZLEMERE 70 CHORLEY NEW ROAD
>   BOLTON LANCASHIRE BL1 4BY None Filed Active - Newly Incorporated ) 1

Below is how it looks in Google Developer tools:

http://i59.tinypic.com/30k36af.png

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue myself. Turns out the returned XML string was using HTML entities and I stupidly didn't realise. Ran the XML string through `html_entity_decode()` before running it through `simplexml_load_string()` and it worked fine.